# Translations for multiple locales/dialects

Tags: apex, customlabel, translation, locale, react

We're developing a managed package that uses the translation workbench to provide translations. We'd like to support multiple English translations so that users with a different locale from En-US can get a different English translation. For example, British English users would get their own versions of at least some translations.

Our front-end is React based, so we have an Apex service that returns the custom label values. We'd like to avoid having to write Apex code to specifically detect the locale. We'd also like to avoid either having fixed strings or custom labels that exist specifically as an alternate label for a different locale.

Is there a better way to create multiple English (or other language) translations that are locale-driven rather than just language-driven?

Comment: Is there a better way than what? Not sure I understand what you're asking...

Comment: For example, I am a user with local EN-US. I open a visualforce page and am greeted with a custom label, "Hello, {Name}". My coworker John is in the UK with a locale of EN-GB and would like to be greeted with "Good day, {Name}" or something like that. The language is still English, but how can we accommodate British or Canadian or etc dialects and vernacular? The best alternative I can think of off-hand is to create labels for, say, alternate-greeting, a duplicate of greeting, and detect the locale for which one we return.

Answer (score 0):

Only primary languages are available by default. In order to translate end-user and platform languages, it is necessary to enable these in org settings. They will not appear as an option in translation workbench until doing so.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=5